# python2.7 - JSON array with mappings to a simpler list?

Tags: python, json

I've been staring at this for the past couple of hours and I'm trying to figure out how to go through this JSON data and end up with a rather simple CSV.

I've done something like this before but it was awhile ago and I ended up converting all the JSON data to xml and used element tree to build the headers and lots of loops. It was a lot of tedious coding and before I go down that road I thought I'd see if there's an easier way to get what I need.

I'm making a call to an online resource and I'm getting the data back like this, I've never dealt with a map before in JSON. I have the following json in a variable called "jdata"

```
            {
                "array": {
                    "headers": ["time",
                    "s_id",
                    "loc_id",
                    "total_1",
                    "total_2",
                    "total_3",
                    "total_4",
                    "total_5"],
                    "m_data": {
                        "end": 1506816000,
                        "map": {
                            "s_id": {
                                "284": "Test12",
                                "13": "AnotherTest4",
                                "5595": "GoogleTest"
                            },
                            "loc_id": {
                                "1": "Unknown",
                                "2": "",
                                "3": "NYC"
                                }
                        },
                        "start": 1506816000,
                        "status": "OK"
                    },
                    "data": [

                    [1506816000,
                    284,
                    3,
                    5350,
                    59202191,
                    null,
                    25499830,
                    938247],

                    [1506816000,
                    13,
                    1,
                    81623,
                    2527480526,
                    null,
                    372601901,
                    13993534],

                    [1506816000,
                    5595,
                    3,
                    61331,
                    40157029547,
                    null,
                    15268999464,
                    60112032]]
                }
            }
```

What I want is the data portions (there can be thousands). The issue is that the data has a map instead of hard setting two of the values I need. (s_id and loc_id)

Is there a way to go through all the data keys and

Instead of this:

```
                    284,3,5350,59202191,null,25499830,938247
```

I want to end up with all the data sections in rows like this:

```
                    Test12,NYC,5350,59202191,null,25499830,938247
```

I can actually do all the CSV stuff myself, if I can just get all of the data entries into a list with the "map" values instead of the "id" values. How can go through all the data and end up with a large list that I can pull from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
def get_value(s_map, loc_map, value_id):
    value_id = str(value_id)
    if value_id in s_map:
        return s_map[value_id]
    elif value_id in loc_map:
        return loc_map[value_id]
    else:
        return value_id


def parse_data(data):
    s_map = data['array']['m_data']['map']['s_id']
    loc_map = data['array']['m_data']['map']['loc_id']

    for element in data['array']['data']:
        element_values = [get_value(s_map, loc_map, val) for val in element]
        yield element_values
```

For your example data:

```
for element in parse_data(data):
    print(element)

> ['1506816000', 'Test12', 'NYC', '5350', '59202191', 'None', '25499830', '938247']
> ['1506816000', 'AnotherTest4', 'Unknown', '81623', '2527480526', 'None', '372601901', '13993534']
> ['1506816000', 'GoogleTest', 'NYC', '61331', '40157029547', 'None', '15268999464', '60112032']
```

Comment: Worked awesome. Apparently "array" wasn't a valid key. I used a JSON "beutifier" and it must have added that. But it works without that on the raw data. Thanks... saved me sooo much time.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are looking for

```
import json
jdata = '''above json'''
pdata = json.loads(jdata)  # converts json to Python data type
map_data = pdata["array"]["m_data"]["map"]
s_id = map_data['s_id']
loc_id = map_data['loc_id']
```